# Application launch without elements

Tags: java, appium, autotest

When I starting application without appium I get this form:
[image]

When I use appium for application launching elements are disappearing:
[image]
Anybody know why it happens?

Java code:

```
    String appPackage = "appPName";
    String appActivity = "appAName";

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Custom Phone");
    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
    cap.setCapability("appPackage", appPackage);
    cap.setCapability("appActivity", appActivity);
    cap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");

    System.out.println("---------------------------------Create session---------------------------------");
    URL device_url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
    try
    {
        driver = new AndroidDriver(device_url, cap);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("----------------------------------Is the application installed?--------------------------------");
    applicationInstalled = driver.isAppInstalled(appPackage);

    System.out.println("Application installed status: " + applicationInstalled);
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");   
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: I suggest you use the desktop version of Appium Server and view the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below capabilities and try.

```
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, false);
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
```

Also, please don't try re-install the app every time you initialize the driver.